# how to get the Root certificates and intermediate certificates for android SSL

Tags: android, performance

i need to implement security measure for my android app which currently runs with http 
I was reading on the ssl and found that we need root and intermediate certificates, 
if i am not purchasing the certificate from outside how can i get the root and intermediate certificates ..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you will be using a self signed or self issued certificate on the public facing server? (Neither of which I would recommend)

If you really want to try and do that then:

- a self signed certificate sign's itself (it is its own CA)
- a self issued certificate on windows for example use the mmc certificates tool, you can download the public part of any certificates in the trust chain (but then you'd need to get them on to a device for them to be useful and something owners of the devices would not like since I would bet you do not have proper key management in place).

A potentially better way would be to use a properly issued certificate for your production site which would allow you to validate the hostname and trust chain correctly.

But for your local dev builds have it ignore these two checks (I would also have it put up a Toast if it was running in this mode so you don't issue this by mistake).